# Считать текст из входящего письма Битрикс

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, не могу понять, как можно считать текст из письма в облачном битриксе. Весь процесс происходит так: Письмо приходит на почту, которая привязана к битриксу. В настройках отмечено, что по входящему письму создается лид. Далее я пытаюсь просмотреть все поля лида на предмет нахождения текста письма, но его там нет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это узнать.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Текст письма не сохраняется непосредственно в поле лида.
Вместо этого создается сущность "Дело", которая прикреплена к данному лиду. И уже в этой сущности можно получить текст письма.
Но сделать это можно только с использованием REST API. Штатных способов в битриксе пока нет.
Ссылка на документаций по API [API Дела](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/rest_help/crm/rest_activity/index.php)